# Add table (aligned text blocks) to plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'd like to add a small table (for example as a legend) to a plot in **R**. I think of something like:

```
t <- wantedTableMethod(
  row("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4")
  , row(value11, value12, value13, cell(value14, adj=0))
  , row(value21, value22, value23, value24)
  , row(value31, value32, value33, cell(value34, adj=1))
  border = F
)
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", t)
```

All values of a column should have the same offset. Is something like this possible in **R**, or do I need to align each value manually?

Comment: What language (or package) are you using to create your object `t` here?

Comment: @mnel: The commands/package is something I'm looking for. My example is written in `fictional R code`. The commands don't exist, as far as I know. I thought it might help to understand what I'm planning to do,...

Answer (score 15):

If you're really averse to external packages, you can accomplish a version of this in `base` R as well:

```
plot(1, 1)
v = 1:9
legend(
  'topright', ncol = 4L, title = 'Table',
  legend = c(
    '', 'Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3',
    'Col1', v[1:3], 
    'Col2', v[4:6], 
    'Col3', v[7:9]
  )
)
```

[image: Displaying the output where a simple plot has a table for a legend. The legend is titled "Table" and shows a 3x3 table with rows labeled "Row1" through "Row3" and similarly for the columns.]

*Caveat coder* that since `v` will be coerced to `character`, you'll have to be careful about float formatting (`sprintf` is your friend). There are also other bells & whistles like `text.col` to help spiffen up the plot a bit more if you'd like.

Comment: this is indeed the best solution for the problem, thanks!

Comment: any idea how to add `pt.bg=c("white","red","yellow","green"), bty="n", pch=22,` inside the legend call but make it displayed only once for each row? at left side of only

Answer (score 14):

The `plotrix` package has a `addtable2plot` function you can pass a `data.frame` or `matrix` to

Using the example from the help page

```
library(plotrix)
testdf<-data.frame(Before=c(10,7,5,9),During=c(8,6,2,5),After=c(5,3,4,3))
 rownames(testdf)<-c("Red","Green","Blue","Lightblue")
 barp(testdf,main="Test addtable2plot",ylab="Value",
  names.arg=colnames(testdf),col=2:5)
 # show most of the options
 addtable2plot(0.7 ,8,testdf,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,
  vlines=TRUE,title="The table")
```

[image]

It is designed to work as similarly to `legend` as possible.

Comment: Makes me want to take a closer look at `plotrix`.  Nifty function.