# Adding a small table to a base graphics multiple plot chart

Tags: r, plot

I have a multiple plot chart:

```
layout(matrix(c(1:4), 2, 2, byrow = FALSE),    widths=c(1,1),  heights=c(1,1))

plot(1:6)
plot(2:7)
plot(3:8)
```

I now want to add a small table in the bottom lower corner. I tried:

```
 library(gridExtra)
 Table1<- data.frame( a=1:6,b=2:7,c=3:8)
 tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
 tbl <- tableGrob(Table1, rows=NULL, theme=tt)
 grid.arrange( tbl)
```

but this does not enter into the lower corner, but creates a new plot.
I would like to be able to solve this problem using base graphics `plot()` rather than `ggplot()`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I use the `plotrix` package to do things like this.  See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406969/add-table-aligned-text-blocks-to-plot-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plotrix you can modify your code as follows:

```
library(plotrix)
Table1<- data.frame( a=1:6,b=2:7,c=3:8)
layout(matrix(c(1:4), 2, 2, byrow = FALSE),    widths=c(1,1),  heights=c(1,1))
plot(1:6)
plot(2:7)
plot(3:8)
plot.new()
addtable2plot(0,0,Table1, 
              xpad=6, ypad=2,
              bty='o',
              display.rownames = TRUE, 
              hlines = TRUE,
              vlines = TRUE, 
              title = "The table")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To treat a table like a plot, try this:

```
library(plotrix)

fm1 <- c(0.40, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1)
fm2 <- c(0.1,   0.15, 0.35,  0.4)
comp <- data.frame(components = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), fm1=fm1, fm2=fm2)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

### Table 
plot(c(0,2), c(0,2), type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
addtable2plot(0,-1,comp,bty="o",display.rownames=FALSE,hlines=TRUE,title="random title", cex=1.5)

### Plot 
plot(1:10)
```