# How to export information from R objects as png?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, flextable, pander

I want to summarize information about my data and export it as a `png` file. I've experimented with packages such as `pander` and `flextable`, but currently can't achieve my goal. Maybe there's a way to get this done using `ggplot2`, but I'm unaware of such.

### Example

Let's say that we have the `mtcars` data, and we want to extract some information about it:

- Number of rows in the data
- Average of `mpg`
- The factor levels available in `cyl`
- Regression summary for predicting `mpg ~ cyl`

To this end, I'll compute each of the above and assign them to objects. Finally, I'll bundle all the info in a list object.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(broom)

number_of_rows <- nrow(mtcars)
mpg_mean       <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
cyl_levels     <- mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% unique() %>% remove_rownames()
model_summary  <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars) %>% broom::tidy()

my_data_summary <- lst(number_of_rows,
                       mpg_mean,
                       cyl_levels,
                       model_summary)


> my_data_summary
## $number_of_rows
## [1] 32

## $mpg_mean
## [1] 20.09062

## $cyl_levels
##   cyl
## 1   6
## 2   4
## 3   8

## $model_summary
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
##   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1 (Intercept)    37.9      2.07      18.3  8.37e-18
## 2 cyl            -2.88     0.322     -8.92 6.11e-10
```

---

**My question:** how can I export `my_data_summary` as a `png`?

---

**Some unsuccessful attempts.**

To note, I'm not particularly motivated to use any specific package.

**1)** I've tried `pander`:

```r
library(pander)

pander(my_data_summary)



  * **number_of_rows**: _32_
  * **mpg_mean**: _20.09_
  * **cyl_levels**:

    -----
     cyl
    -----
      6

      4

      8
    -----

  * **model_summary**:

    ------------------------------------------------------------
        term       estimate   std.error   statistic    p.value
    ------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
     (Intercept)    37.88       2.074       18.27     8.369e-18

         cyl        -2.876     0.3224       -8.92     6.113e-10
    ------------------------------------------------------------


<!-- end of list -->
```

This indeed gets me pretty far, but insufficient. How can I get from such markdown textual output to a *rendered* png?

---

**2)** I've also tried `flextable`.

```r
library(flextable)

flextable(my_data_summary)
```

> Error in flextable(.) : is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE

OK, so `flextable()` accepts only `data.frame` class.

I therefore could have done something like:

```r
flextable(my_data_summary$model_summary)
```

Which then gives this nice output that can be saved to `png` with `flextable::save_as_image()`:
[image: model_summary]

However, the problem with `flextable(my_data_summary$model_summary)` is that I want to get the entire contents of `my_data_summary` rendered and exported to that single `png`, similar to how `pander()` accepts the list object in its entirety.

**Also important to note** that I execute this code via `Rscript`, so I need a solution that is not interactive/GUI-based.

---

### Desired Output

A `png` file that represents `my_data_summary` object and looks something like:

[image]

Any ideas on this?

---

EDIT

---

Based on @Waldi's answer below, I'd like to emphasize that I'm looking for a solution that could be run in a single code run, without creating intermediate temporary files. In other words, I'm trying to come up with a code that has a single output: a `png` file of `my_data_summary` contents.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `webshot` package.
As `webshot` relies on `phantom.js` the first step is to run:

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

Then create `test.Rmd` file :

````
---
title: test
output: html_document
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = F)`

```{r,results='asis'}
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(broom)

number_of_rows <- nrow(mtcars)
mpg_mean       <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
cyl_levels     <- mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% unique() %>% remove_rownames()
model_summary  <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars) %>% broom::tidy()

my_data_summary <- lst(number_of_rows,
                       mpg_mean,
                       cyl_levels,
                       model_summary)

library(pander)

pander(my_data_summary)
```
````

You are now ready to output `png`:

```
webshot::rmdshot('test.Rmd','test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is close to the desired output, but I'm unable to rely on such intermediate `.rmd` step. That is, writing to `.rmd` file and then reading it with `webshot::rmdshot()` is a problem. Is there a way to workout a similar workflow in a single run, without saving to `.rmd` in-between?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no other idea yet on how to make it in a single run without intermediate `.Rmd`

Comment: @Emman Why is this a problem? Are you aware that you could dynamicaly *generate* that intermediate RMD file from a script (e.g. in a temporary directory)?

Comment: @CL The issue isn't dynamic generation, that's easy enough. But this script is executed via `Rscript` on a remote server, and the certain server setup makes such intermediate saving too painful in terms of writing and reading.

Comment: @Emman, I understand you can configure the server to accept `.png` write, but intermediate html generation in a `tempdir()` isn't an option?

Comment: @Waldi I'm not the person who maintains the server so I need to adhere to inflexibilities others have set. The intermediate writing strategy would be my last resort but only if there's absolutely no way to get a `png` in a single run. But this is strange no? Because `pander()` already gives us the info in markdown syntax. It's just the rendering step that's missing.

Comment: The problem is that usual markdown rendering is `html` or `pdf`, not `png`. `webshot` actually renders in `html`, opens the `html` in a `phantom.js` browser and takes a screen copy... Not very straight forward, but could be used as a workaround

Comment: Then is it reasonable to expect a necessary installation of `phantom.js` on the server (for `webshot` to work)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this but yes : webshot comes with `webshot::install_phantomjs`. I'm going to update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes so that would be another limitation to this solution. I should also note that markdown isn't a requirement for me. I just used `pander()` as an example. I don't really care what underlying method is used to get a `png` output. In fact I'm pretty surprised there's no `ggplot2` method for such a task. When I started tackling this problem I thought it was going to be super trivial.

Comment: Another option would be a simple `plot.new(); plot.window(0:1, 0:1); text(...); legend(...); dev.off()`, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406969/add-table-aligned-text-blocks-to-plot-in-r). Quite limited because you have to calculate position of text & legend = table, but could be sufficient depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlTable package which has the function to concatenate multiple html tables

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(broom)
number_of_rows <- nrow(mtcars)
mpg_mean       <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
cyl_levels     <- mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% unique() %>% remove_rownames()
model_summary  <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars) %>% broom::tidy()

my_data_summary <- lst(number_of_rows,
                       mpg_mean,
                       cyl_levels,
                       model_summary)


#Using htmlTable
library(htmlTable)

#converting each element of the list into invidual html table and concatenating 
concatHtmlTables(list(htmlTable(my_data_summary[[1]]), 
                  htmlTable(txtRound(my_data_summary[[2]], 4)),
                  htmlTable(my_data_summary[[3]]),
                  htmlTable(txtRound(my_data_summary[[4]], 4))), 
             headers = names(my_data_summary))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how do we go from `concatHtmlTables()` to end up with a `png` file?