# How to export an R object to HTML file without writing first to .Rmd?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I want to print the content of R objects and save it as a rendered HTML file. To this end, I find the `pander` package useful. However, I don't know how to go from the markdown `pander::pander()` generates to an HTML file *in a single code execution, without intermediate save to .Rmd file*. This question comes after [a different question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67042357/6105259) about getting a `png` export for the same process.

I'm going to use the same example I used in the other post.

### Example

Let's say that we have the `mtcars` data, and we want to extract some information about it:

- Number of rows in the data
- Average of `mpg`
- The factor levels available in `cyl`
- Regression summary for predicting `mpg ~ cyl`

To this end, I'll compute each of the above and assign them to objects. Finally, I'll bundle all the info in a list object.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(broom)

number_of_rows <- nrow(mtcars)
mpg_mean       <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
cyl_levels     <- mtcars %>% select(cyl) %>% unique() %>% remove_rownames()
model_summary  <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars) %>% broom::tidy()

my_data_summary <- lst(number_of_rows,
                       mpg_mean,
                       cyl_levels,
                       model_summary)


> my_data_summary
## $number_of_rows
## [1] 32

## $mpg_mean
## [1] 20.09062

## $cyl_levels
##   cyl
## 1   6
## 2   4
## 3   8

## $model_summary
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
##   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1 (Intercept)    37.9      2.07      18.3  8.37e-18
## 2 cyl            -2.88     0.322     -8.92 6.11e-10
```

---

So how can I print the contents of `my_data_summary` as an HTML file?
I thought that `pander::pander()` is a good candidate because it accepts the list object in its entirety.

```r
library(pander)

> pander(my_data_summary)

  * **number_of_rows**: _32_
  * **mpg_mean**: _20.09_
  * **cyl_levels**:

    -----
     cyl
    -----
      6

      4

      8
    -----

  * **model_summary**:

    ------------------------------------------------------------
        term       estimate   std.error   statistic    p.value
    ------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
     (Intercept)    37.88       2.074       18.27     8.369e-18

         cyl        -2.876     0.3224       -8.92     6.113e-10
    ------------------------------------------------------------


<!-- end of list -->
```

But now I'm stuck. How could I progress from `pander(my_data_summary)` to an `.html` file in my directory? I want an `.html` that when opened, looks like this:

[image: html_file]

---

Is there a way to write a single code that goes directly from `my_data_summary` to an `.html` export ***without*** generating an intermediate file?

Thanks!

---

EDIT 1

---

@Konrad commented that it's impossible to progress from `pander`'s markdown output directly. So if we ignore `pander`, is there any way to export the contents of `my_data_summary` to an HTML file directly?

---

EDIT 2

---

I made some progress with `pander`.

```r
info_as_chr_vec <-
  my_data_summary %>%
  pander::pander_return() %>%
  paste(., collapse = "\n")

info_as_chr_vec %>%
  pander::Pandoc.brew(text = ., output = ~path/to/html/output/file, convert = "html")
```

Which writes an `html` file. This seems OK:
[image: html_output]

But I dislike the unnecessary *table of contents* and the footer. Nor do I know how to change the overall style of the tables. I'd much rather to have something more plain. Obviously, I could have edited the `html` code after the fact. But the whole point is to get the desired `html` file in the original execution of the `R` code.

Comment: ‘pander’ generates Markdown, not HTML. And the ‘knitr’/‘rmarkdown’ packages that generate HTML from Markdown require *files* as input. So this is fundamentally not possible. But you can just wrap the whole process inside a function via a temporary RMarkdown file which is deleted at the end of the function, so for  the user of the function the process is completely opaque.

Comment: OK I feared from such an answer. So pander aside, there's no way to export the contents of R objects to html (without intermediate files)?

Comment: There are other packages that might do direct HTML export; check out ‘kableExtra’, ‘huxtable’, ‘htmlTable’.

Comment: From your other question and your comments there, I conclude that this is supposed to run on a server that you do not control and probably there is no directory on the server where you're supposed to create files - am I right? (Even) if this is the case ... why can't you just call `tempdir()`? I'm not trying to challenge your requirements - but maybe your restrictions are not as severe as you think they are. And if you *can* write to a temporary directory, it looks like many of your problems would just ... vanish.

Comment: @CL, I appreciate your feedback. Would you mind providing code that I could try running? Sorry, this is unfamiliar territory for me...

Comment: @Emman To start, you could try running this: https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/24ca31f65ed8d1a762634d145d608adf This should render a table as PDF in a temporary directory. If that works, you have plenty of options. You can use webshot to generate pictures from HTML (as Waldi told you in your other question) or generate PDFs and convert them to PNG, etc.

Comment: @CL. thanks for taking the time to write the gist. Unfortunately it failed for me. I commented on the gist with the log, as it's too verbose to include in here. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks :)